# If $\mu$ is a semifinite mesure and $\mu(E) = \infty$, then for any $C > 0$ there exists $F \subset E$ with $C < \mu(F) < \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is problem 1.14 from Folland's *Real Analysis*.

I am aware of a few solutions to this problem (for example, [If a measure is semifinite, then there are sets of arbitrarily large but finite measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234930/if-a-measure-is-semifinite-then-there-are-sets-of-arbitrarily-large-but-finite)). However I am having trouble with one step. It is clear that we need to show that
$$ s = \sup\{\mu(F) : F \in \mathcal{M}, F \subset E, \mu(F) < \infty\} = \infty.$$

In all of the proofs the approach is to assume by way of contradiction that $s < \infty$. Then they claim that there must exist a sequence of sets $F_n \subset E$ with $\mu(F_n)< \infty$ and $\mu(F_n)→ s$. But why? What ensures the existence of such a sequence of sets? What if my set of measures is finite so I do not have such a nice continuum?

Similarly another solution states that if $s = \alpha$ and $\alpha<\infty$, then $\alpha-1/n<\alpha$, so for every $n$ there exists $F_n\subset E$ with $\alpha-1/n<\mu(F_n)<\infty$. What gaurantees the existence of such a set?

Would anyone be able to walk me through this proof in more detail that is in the post? Thanks!

Comment: $F_n$'s exist by definition of supremum of  a set of real numbers. This has nothing to do with measure theory.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks! Is there a name for that property?