# Definition of semi-finite measure

Tags: measure-theory

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-finite_measure) a semi-finite measure is defined as follows:

> **Definition:** Let $( X ,\mathcal{ A} )$ be a measurable space and $\mu$ a measure on this measurable space. The measure $\mu$ is called an s-finite measure, if it can be written as a countable sum of finite measures $\nu_{n}(n \in N)$,
> $$
>     \mu = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\nu_{n}
> $$

On the other hand there are several places where the following definition is used ([Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234168/a-question-on-semifinite-measures))

> **Definition:** Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space. If for
> each $E \in \mathcal{M}$ with $\mu(E) = \infty$, there exists $F \in
> \mathcal{M}$ with $F \subset E$ and $0 < \mu(F) < \infty$, $\mu$ is
> called semifinite.

I think theses definitions are equivalent but how can I prove this?

Answer (score 1):

They are not equivalent. Let $\mu(A)=|A|$. Then $\mu$ satisfies the second definition, as every nonempty set contains a point, but not the first, because the real numbers are uncountable.

Comment: That's true. But I'm confused. Do you have a source with the definition for semi-finite measures?

Comment: I have the one you gave me! If you choose a different definition, you might get a different result.